# C++ getting access to SingleTune class member methods getting Member access into incomplete type

Tags: c++, singleton

i have simple singleton that holds another class as its member 
i try to access this member class public methods and i get :

```
Member access into incomplete type
```

my singleton class :

```
#include "SoundManager.h"
class Singleton : pSoundManager(new SoundManager())
{
  public:
static
  Singleton getInstance()
  {
    if (!instance_)
      {
        instance_ = new Singleton();
      }

    return instance_;
  }
  SoundManager*  getSoundManager( return pSoundManager;);
  private:
    static Singleton* instance_;
    Singleton() {};
    ~Singleton(){};
    SoundManager* pSoundManager;

}
```

//the class that kept in the singleton

```
class SoundManager
{
public:
    SoundManager(){};
    ~SoundManager(){};


    unsigned int playEffect() {printf("effect!!");};

private:


};
```

and now when i try to do

```
Singleton::getInstance()->getSoundManager()->playEffect() ;
```

im getting :

```
Member access into incomplete type 'SoundManager'
```

what im doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you miss to include the declaration of `SoundManager`?

Comment: no its there i juts didn't set it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
SoundManager* getSoundManager( return pSoundManager;);
```

is syntactically wrong in a way the error messages you see could get misleading. Replace this code with

```
SoundManager* getSoundManager() { return pSoundManager; }
```

---

What I would do is, simplifying the `getInstance()` function a bit (besides fixing some of the obvious syntactic errors):

```
#include "SoundManager.h"

class Singleton {
  public:
static
  Singleton& getInstance() {
    static Singleton instance_;
    return instance_;
  }

  SoundManager& getSoundManager() { return soundManager_; }
  private:
    Singleton() {};
    ~Singleton(){};
    SoundManager soundManager_;    
};
```

Calling the `playEffect()` function would change to

```
Singleton::getInstance().getSoundManager().playEffect();
```

accordingly of course.

Comment: Thanks this is the answer , can you tell me why its not accepting using return as pointer and only as return reference to member ?

Comment: @user63898 It would have accepted returning a pointer as well (I mentioned you had some basic syntactical flaws). Though I think returning references is the cleaner way to make it work. I've edited to make this clearer in 1st place.

Comment: i see , i always confuse why sometimes i need to return pointer (save memory ?? only copy 4 k)
and way should i return as reference as you did , where can i learn for once what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The

```
class Singleton : pSoundManager(new SoundManager())
```

is not valid C++ construction. The g++ compiler cannot eat it. You should move it into the constructor. Probably it is an issue.

Additionally, you should explicitly initialize the instance_ member to the NULL value because the C++ standard says that the not-initialized members contain unpredicted values. So, the

```
if (!instance_)
```

condition can be false without first initialization.